# Play .WMV File In Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to create a Windows Form application to play .WMV files.

I have 5 videos that i have added to my project, within a Videos folder.

I have created a button for each video, 5.

When a button is clicked, Button1, i want to be able to open Video1.. Using Windows Media Player for example.

Code so far::

```
    private void PlayVideo1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open Windows Media Player
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("wmplayer.exe");

        // Play Video1.
        Process.Start("Video1.wmv");
    }
```

Please can you advise what i am doing wrong?

========================

Update:

Can a similar code be used for WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the WMV files set to "Copy always" in the "Copy to output Directory" property? Like in the picture below:

[image: Example]

If it is, then the files are going to the same directory as the application, the next step is to run the WMV from the propert path,

Your code:

```
Process.Start("Video1.wmv");
```

Is not wrong to want to start the WMV directly (that way, the default player in the target machine will run), but you need to send the full path (C:\Video.WMV for eg)

If the WMV files are inside a VIDEOS folder within your application, you could change to do like this for eg:

```
Process.Start(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "VIDEOS/Video1.wmv"));
```

Comment: Thanks Hamarict. I set the Output to Copy Always and used Process.Start(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "VIDEOS/Video1.wmv"));

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Audio Video Playback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb324497.aspx) from `Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback` namespace.

or use `Windows Media Player Control` on your form. see this MSDN article:

- [Using the Windows Media Player Control in a .NET Framework Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564582.aspx)

a sample code:

```
private void PlayFile(String url)
{
    Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    Player.URL = url;
    Player.controls.play();
}
```